# Poisson Random Variables - Application problem

Tags: probability

On a random day, the number of vacant rooms of a big hotel in New York City is 35, on average. What
is the probability that next Saturday this hotel has at least 30 vacant rooms?

I know the answer is 0.823 but do not understand how they got this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a random variable $X$ to be the number of vacant rooms of a big hotel. Since the title is Poisson Random Variables, let's assume that this random variable is distributed Poisson. Since you know there are 35 vacant rooms on average, you have that $E(X) = 35$, so you know the parameter of your distribution. You are asked to find the probability there are at least 30 vacant rooms, this is just $P(X=30) + P(X = 31) + ....$ or $ 1 - (P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) + ... P(X = 29)) $ Both should evaluate to your desired answer, if I am not mistaken!

Comment: Is there an easier way to calculate it though? Because other wise you would have to add 30 terms to be subtracted from one, which seems a bit time consuming...

Comment: Use a normal approximation via the central limit theorem? See the lower half of https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/180